# My jQuery 'KeyCode' code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

> Question

Hello, I am quite new to jQuery so although it may sound stupid to some people, I really am not sure why this code isn't working. [My JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwdmugt4/1/)

A basic explanation of what it is supposed to do is:

Start Up by clicking the start button << This works

Show the previously hidden circular div which is circular from the 
'border-radius: 100%' CSS code included bellow. << This Works

Make the div move with Up, Down, Left and Right << This **Does NOT** work

That is currently my problem. I have attached on all 3 files which I included in this task.

> HTML

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = 'script.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id='runner'></div>

<div id='start'>START!</div>

</body>

</html>
```

> CSS

```
    body{

    background-color: black;

}

#runner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position:relative
    left: 0;
    top: 0;;
}

#start{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -32.5px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

> Javascript Code

```
var main = function()
        {

        var $runner = $('#runner');
        var $start = $('#start');

        //  STARTUP


        $runner.hide();

        $start.mouseenter(function(){

            $start.css('width', '210px');
            $start.css('height', '80px');

        });

        $start.mouseleave(function(){

            $start.css('width', '200px');
            $start.css('height', '75px');

        });

        $start.click(function(){

            $start.hide();
            $runner.show();
            $(document).keydown(function(key){

            switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
                // Left arrow key pressed
                case 37:
                    $('#runner').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 1);
                    break;
                // Up Arrow Pressed
                case 38:
                    // Put our code here
                    $('#runner').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 1);
                    break;
                // Right Arrow Pressed
                case 39:
                    // Put our code here
                    $('#runner').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 1);
                    break;
                // Down Arrow Pressed
                case 40:
                    // Put our code here
                    $('#runner').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 1);
                    break;
            }

            })


        });

        //  STARTUP FINISHED

        //  GAME

    }

    $(document).ready(main);
```

So this is my code and I am really not sure why it isn't working. Any suggestions as to why not?

If you think you might see the problem or know an alternative way to do it, please answer your thoughts. *I have included a JSfiddle link that just shows the output:* [My JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwdmugt4/1/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got errors in the CSS code. It's working fine otherwise :)

Corrected CSS :

```
#runner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/gwdmugt4/3/)

Comment: +Vincent G I feel so dopey. Thank you for your answer. I must have added an accidental ; on top :)

Comment: You're welcome ! Exactly yes. A very small error, the JS code works fine :)

Comment: +Vincent G If I may ask, how would you recommend approaching the issue of the div leaving the screen? I don't want to let it go out of the screen's space. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you can for instance test the position of the `#runner` to see if there are negative one. If so, you don't set the movement, else you do :) I've made logs here to help you but I let you do the rest of the code ;) 
See it here https://jsfiddle.net/gwdmugt4/6/

Answer (score 0):

You've got errors in the CSS code and jQuery value assign issue(+=10px). It's working fine otherwise :)

Css correction:

```
#runner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

jQuery Correction:

```
var a = 10;

    $start.click(function(){



        $start.hide();
        $runner.show();
        $(document).keydown(function(key){

        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
        a -= 10;
                $('#runner').animate({left: a+"px"}, 1);
                break;
            // Up Arrow Pressed
            case 38:
        a -= 10;
                // Put our code here
                $('#runner').animate({top: a+"px"}, 1);
                break;
            // Right Arrow Pressed
            case 39:
        a += 10;
                // Put our code here
                $('#runner').animate({left: a+"px"}, 1);
                break;
            // Down Arrow Pressed
            case 40:
        a += 10;
                // Put our code here
                $('#runner').animate({top: a+"px"}, 1);
                break;
        }

        })


    });
```